# Re-Install Windows on Server with HP Smart Array

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, hp-smart-array

We have a server with an HP Smart Array 642 attached to it with a MSA20 enclosure, and want to format the OS and start over going from Server 2003 to Server 2008 R2, however want to keep the data on the Array. The OS is installed on the local server internal drives.

I looked on HP's site for some information on this, but can't seem to find any. General comments I am reading about HP's Smart Array seem to say that the arrays are pretty flexible.

Data is backed up. My plan was to shutdown the server, disconnect the cable to the enclosure, boot and re-install Windows, and re-install the drivers and software for the array, and I assume the RAID information and configuration would still be on the controller, and I would be able to access to array as before.

Any flaws or oversights in my plan? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in your assumptions and approach, both the controller and the disks store array configuration, just make sure you use the latest PSP, make sure it installs everything and is booting without error, then reconnect, you may have to reboot again.

Best of luck, oh and that card is definitely supported by W2K8 :)

Comment: went smoothly!!

Comment: Great news, well done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncertain of your abilities to do this right, unplug the connection to the array, install, and plug it back in.  The controller should retain all the information (as you can access it via the BIOS, before the system boots for recovery).  The config may be stored on the drives themselves, but either way, the boot disk should not store the only copy of the config.

If you are REALLY uncertain, install onto a temporary or new internal drive first, keeping your old one fully intact.